# Is there a way to get server thumbprint from code that is running on same server?

Tags: java, x509certificate

I want to get server thumbprint from the java code that is being executed on the server itself. I have read somethings on it and it seems like eveyone is suggesting extracting it from the certificate itself. Is there any way to get it without using the certificate, maybe like opening up a httpconnection/httprequest or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the certificate from the server using the SSL connection. [Here is an example](http://www.xinotes.org/notes/note/1088/).
2. Compute the thumbprint (hash)

Comment: Thanks Krumelur. Above link was very useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to use a new TrustManager and it was breaking over there. I removed it and used the rest of the code and it worked.

```
static X509TrustManager tm = new X509TrustManager()
{

    @Override
    public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("synthetic-access")
    @Override
    public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] arg0, String arg1)
            throws CertificateException
    {


    }

    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    // public static X509Certificate[] getChain() { return chain; }

};


TrustManager[] tm1 = { tm };
SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
sslContext.init(null, tm1, new SecureRandom());
sslFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslFactory.createSocket("localhost", port);
// timeout: 10secs
sslSocket.setSoTimeout(10 * 1000); 
sslSocket.startHandshake();

// add certificate to keystore
X509Certificate[] vCenterServerCert = chain;

 for (int i = 0; i < vCenterServerCert.length; i++) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            byte[] der = vCenterServerCert[i].getEncoded();
            md.update(der);
            byte[] digest = md.digest();

            System.out.print("-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n");
            System.out.print(hexify(digest));
            //System.out.print(new sun.misc.BASE64Encoder().encode(servercerts[i].getEncoded()));
            System.out.print("\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n");

        }
```